# Issue when writing chinese characters into a simple txt file

Tags: c#, .net, file

```
--------------------------------
CHECK#:555               COVER:2
      25 !六月 14 12:31:45       
|2CTBL!檯號|2C: 53 / 1 
--------------------------------
1  Pickles/plate        2.00 
2  Water @0.50          1.00 
1  !锅贴套餐A           16.80 
1  !锅贴套餐B           16.80 

   SUBTOTAL:           36.60 
   SERV CHG 10%:        3.66 
                    ---------
                       40.26
```

When I'm writing same text to another text file its not displaying chinese character

Comment: i already done font setting in notepad and install Chinese fonts into system

Comment: How you are writting it to the other file? Whats the code?

Comment: Are you sure you are properly encoding the file? Notepad is not the best unicode aware application. Try notepad++

Comment: using  StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(OutputPath,false ,Encoding.UTF8);
                        sw.Write(sb.ToString());
                        sw.Flush();
                        sw.Close();

Comment: where sb is my string content of file and oupputpath is path where file get saved

Comment: no i dont want to use notepad++ i tried the same thing in my system its working fine but in another system my code is not working i have done same setting on it.

Comment: Can you show the code to read the file? And the resulting text?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Encoding.Unicode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.unicode.aspx), it's called so for a reason. It will result in 2 bytes/char encoding, should be no problem with saving C# *unicode string* into file.

The only question left is how do you check what was written? To example, I am not sure in XP Notepad (but Win7 one is ok). You could do a simple test: write something, then read and compare in C#. Content should match.

```
string write = "some Chinese characters here";
using(var writer = new StreamWriter("blablabla", false, Encoding.Unicode)
    writer.Write(write);
using(var reader = new StreamReader("blablabla", Encoding.Unicode)
{
    var read = reader.ReadToEnd();
    if(read != write)
        throw new Exception("omg");
}
```

Other thing could be that

```
sw.Write(sb.ToString());
```

are you sure `sb.ToString()` will produce what you expect it will?

Answer (score 0):

Try a different encoding when writing the file. [Here is a list of a few](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encodinginfo.getencoding.aspx)

Comment: What about `Chinese Traditional (Big5)` or `Chinese Simplified (GB2312)`. Also make sure you read the file with correct encoding.

Comment: check above code i given utf-8 encoding when i am creating another file